# loop through multiple unstructured txt files to insert into MySql using DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have multiple txt files in a directory and I want to insert all of them into mysql; the content of each file show should occupy a row. In MySQL, I have 2 columns: ID (auto increment), and LastName(nvarchar(45)). First, I used insert into, and I got the error that I cannot insert too many lines! Then, I used the following code, but it gives me error 1064. Here is the code:

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
import os
result = os.listdir("path")
for x in result:
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","myblog")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    file = os.path.join('path\\'+x)    
    cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file INTO clamp_test(ID, LastName)");   
    file.close()          
db.commit()
db.close
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? Is this the right way to insert multiples lines of an unstructhered file into MySql?

Comment: `OS error code  64:  Machine is not on the network`

Comment: @Sammitch; my bad! it was 1064. It says syntax is not correct, but I double checked it and it was correct

Comment: Then spencer's answer is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is the string literal containing the SQL text

```
 "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file INTO ..."
                         ^^^^
```

Here, `file` is just characters that are part of the literal string. It's not a reference to a variable to be evaluated.

The SQL statement we need to send to MySQL would need to look like

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/mydir/myfile.txt' INTO ...
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In the code, it looks like what we want to happen is to have the variable file evaluated, and the result of the evaluation incorporated that into the SQL text string.

Something like this:

```
 "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s'  INTO ... " % (file)
```

Comment: thanks! But I am still getting the same error: cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE clamp_test %(file1)"); and error is still  code 1064.  @spencer7593

Comment: This is python code, isn't it? Seems like you missed the double quote terminating the string.  The **`% (file)`** bit isn't part of the string literal, that's some python syntax to get a variable evaluated and stuck into a string, akin to C (or perl or bash) **`sprintf`** function. (Don't send the `%s` to MySQL. MySQL doesn't know what to do with that. Send MySQL an actual filename `... INFILE '/mydir/myfile.txt' INTO ...`